# Parse timetable to group timeframes together to determine open and close times

Tags: datetime, go, parsing

I have this object that I am getting from an API it has a timetable of a restaurant on a specific day:

```
restaurantTimetable := []string {
    "2023-05-27T11:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T11:30:00",
    "2023-05-27T12:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T12:30:00",
    "2023-05-27T13:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T13:30:00",
    "2023-05-27T14:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T18:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T18:30:00",
    "2023-05-27T19:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T19:30:00",
    "2023-05-27T20:00:00",
    "2023-05-27T20:30:00",
    "2023-05-27T21:00:00",
}
```

I want to parse it to something similar to this, so that we have the open and close times of that day:

```
[
  {
    "open": {
      "time": "1100",
      "hours": 11,
      "minutes": 0,
      "nextDate": 0
    },
    "close": {
      "time": "1400",
      "hours": 14,
      "minutes": 0,
      "nextDate": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "open": {
      "time": "1800",
      "hours": 18,
      "minutes": 0,
      "nextDate": 0
    },
    "close": {
      "time": "2100",
      "hours": 21,
      "minutes": 0,
      "nextDate": 0
    }
  }
]
```

This is what I did so far but I am not getting the right result, I am not sure what's wrong exactly:

```
func ParseTimetable(timetable []string) ([]map[string]map[string]interface{}, error) {
  const layout = "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
  
  slots := make([]map[string]map[string]interface{}, 0)
  
  for i := 0; i+1 < len(timetable); i += 2 {
    startSlot := timetable[i]
    endSlot := timetable[i+1]
    
    // parse start and end times as time.Time objects
    startTime, err := time.Parse(layout, startSlot)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
    endTime, err := time.Parse(layout, endSlot)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
    
    startHour, startMinute, _ := startTime.Clock()
    endHour, endMinute, _ := endTime.Clock()
    
    slot := map[string]map[string]interface{}{
      "open": {
        "time":     fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d", startHour, startMinute),
        "hours":    startHour,
        "minutes":  startMinute,
        "nextDate": 0,
      },
      "close": {
        "time":     fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d", endHour, endMinute),
        "hours":    endHour,
        "minutes":  endMinute,
        "nextDate": 0,
      },
    }
    
    slots = append(slots, slot)
  }
  
  return slots, nil
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, if anyone can guide here I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
func parseTimetable(timetable []string, day int) ([]map[string]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    const layout = "2006-01-02T15:04:05"

    slots := make([]map[string]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    startSlot := timetable[0]
    endSlot := ""
    for i := 1; i < len(timetable); i += 1 {
        timeSlot, err := time.Parse(layout, timetable[i])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        previousTimeSlot, err := time.Parse(layout, timetable[i-1])
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if timeSlot == previousTimeSlot.Add(30*time.Minute) && i+1 < len(timetable) {
            continue
        }

        if i == len(timetable)-1 {
            endSlot = timetable[i]
        } else {
            endSlot = timetable[i-1]
        }
        startTime, err := time.Parse(layout, startSlot)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        endTime, err := time.Parse(layout, endSlot)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        startHour, startMinute, _ := startTime.Clock()
        endHour, endMinute, _ := endTime.Clock()

        slot := map[string]map[string]interface{}{
            "open": {
                "day":      day,
                "time":     fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d", startHour, startMinute),
                "hours":    startHour,
                "minutes":  startMinute,
                "nextDate": 0,
            },
            "close": {
                "day":      day,
                "time":     fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d", endHour, endMinute),
                "hours":    endHour,
                "minutes":  endMinute,
                "nextDate": 0,
            },
        }

        slots = append(slots, slot)

        startSlot = timetable[i]
        endSlot = ""
    }

    return slots, nil
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best solution but for now it works, if anyone has any suggestions on how to optimize this let me know.